# Layout/design templates for MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there any open source design templates available for asp.net MVC projects? Tired of seeing the standard blue and white look that every mvc projects have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you understand html/css you can take benefit of all websites that offers free template, to name but a few:

- http://www.oswd.org/
- http://www.sixshootermedia.com/free-templates/
- http://www.opendesigns.org/

That's just a matter of applying them to your ASP.NET MVC Website (override the default CSS and updating the _layout markup), see [this article](http://www.deepakchitnis.net/how-to-use-free-css-templates-with-aspnet-mvc-3.aspx).

Or there is the [MVC Contrib Template gallery](http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Those template sites seem to be outdated now and no longer kept going, just fyi.

http://oswd.co and http://html5up.net look to be more recent with the latter having a lot of HTML5 templates to choose from.